Spark Driver runs out of memory loading a query from a JDBC driver
Here is the issue. I need to load data from a remote database, with a bit of an awkward query:
query = f"""
    (SELECT id, key, MAX(time) AS created_at
    FROM remote.table
    WHERE remote_id = {id}
    AND id IN ({contact_ids_str})
    GROUP BY id, key) as subquery
"""

The contact_ids_str is a rather lengthy string of 50,000 ids. The total statement it probably 8MB in size. This seems cause an issue on the jdbc driver.
Next up i read the data using the spark jdbc driver
    df = spark.read.format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", jdbc_url) \
    .option("dbtable", query) \
    .option("user", jdbc_properties["user"]) \
    .option("password", jdbc_properties["password"]) \
    .option("driver", jdbc_properties["driver"]) \
    .load()

    print(f"Query {df.count()} rows returned.")
    df.write.csv('/home/slake/checkpoints/temp/', header=True, mode="append")

After this i delete any dataframe and the files are written to disk. This works but only for 30-40 queries. After this the spark driver runs out of memory. The dataframe it self is not the memory problem though. It seems to be a memory issue on the jdbc driver itself. Because when i first create a view (using psycopg2) with the original query on the postgres db with the huge query and then make spark load from the view itself, the memory issue disappears.
So the question is, is this a problem i can solve without doing the work around with psycopg2
For example forcing a jdbc memory cleanup or something like it.
Update: work around
Since i was stuck with this i created a work around for myself. What i did is before i start run the spark jdbc read, first i connect with psycopg2 and create a view on the postgres server with the original query
create_view_query = f"""
    CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW {view_name} AS
    SELECT id, key, MAX(time) AS created_at
    FROM remote.table
    WHERE remote_id = {id}
    AND id IN ({contact_ids_str})
    GROUP BY id, key
"""

Then using we load the data from the view instead of using the really big query instead. This works fine, without any memory issues what so ever (100mb total memory usage, where as the original was consuming 1gb after 50 queries). But it is obviously a work around. I would really like to know if there is a way to cleanup the table query names from the spark memory.
Solution
As it turns out the memory issues resulted from the spark ui - even though i turned off the ui, the logs were stored in memory anyway.
Setting spark.ui.store.path /home/stats/datalake/tmpdir/ui is what solved my issue.
Seems obvious from the documentation:
Local directory where to cache application information for live UI. By default this is not set, meaning all application information will be kept in memory.
Maybe it will help someone else as well.

Please share the error details

You can split you contract id list of 50000 items in for example 50 batches of 1000 items and create 1 partition by batch
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

def split_list(lst, n):
    """Split the list into chunks of size n"""
    for i in range(0, len(lst), n):
        yield lst[i:i + n]

# Example contact_ids list
contact_ids = [str(i) for i in range(10000)]  # Example list of contact ids

# Split the list into partitions of 1000
partitions = list(split_list(contact_ids, 1000))

# Initialize Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("ExampleApp") \
    .getOrCreate()

# SQL query template
query_template = """
    (SELECT id, key, MAX(time) AS created_at
    FROM remote.table
    WHERE remote_id = {id}
    AND id IN ({contact_ids_str})
    GROUP BY id, key) as subquery
"""

# Your remote_id value
remote_id = 'some_remote_id_value'  # Replace with your actual remote_id

dfs = []

for partition in partitions:
    contact_ids_str = ', '.join(partition)
    query = query_template.format(id=remote_id, contact_ids_str=contact_ids_str)
    df = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", "jdbc:your_database_url") \
                   .option("dbtable", query) \
                   .option("user", "your_db_user") \
                   .option("password", "your_db_password") \
                   .load()
    dfs.append(df)

# Union all DataFrames
result_df = dfs[0]
for df in dfs[1:]:
    result_df = result_df.union(df)


I tried this during my  trial and errors. But it still fills up the driver memory eventually, because instead of 50 really large query strings i end up with 5000 shorter but eventually equally long query strings. I am fairly confident the issue is that the spark job stores the Table configuration somewhere in memory and since the the table configuration in this case is a very long query the driver memory ends up full with a OOM as a result.

do you run your spark locally ? on how many cores with how much driver memory and executors ?

I actually figured it out after 4 frustrating days, the issue was i hadn't set spark.ui.store.path, and even though i had turned off the UI, the logs it needs was still accumulating data which is stored in memory, without that setting.
